# Newsboat: How to get more than 15 articles?

Tags: command-line, newsboat

I am using [Newsboat](https://newsboat.org/), and YouTube feeds seems to be populated with the latest 15 posts.

How do I manipulate this number?

I would like to modify non-youtube feeds as well.

Comment: While this isn't off topic here, I think you'd be better off asking on one of their support channels. Their website mentions a mailing group and a live chat.

Comment: Related: [How to use YouTube Data API (v3) to get more than 15 videos in an RSS reader (newsboat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430703/how-to-use-youtube-data-api-v3-to-get-more-than-15-videos-in-an-rss-reader-ne)

Comment: I've already checked it. The solution provided there is not viable for my use case as I am looking for a way to control the articles number for all my feeds whereas the post concluded with a with a fixed numbered (50) solution and it's only for youtube.